# How to make textbox responsive the right way?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make the search text box responsive fill the whole screen.
I make it work but the orange button and advance **dropdown menu** is in the second line.

This is my CSS code for the search bar

```
.form-group.footable-filtering-search {
  width: 100%;
}
.footable .input-group-btn {
  display: block;
}
```

This is the page https://www.test.com/

Check prices table

What I have tried:

I tried to set the textbox for **width:80%** and the `input-group-btn` to `flex`.

But it completely disappear.
I tried with contain too the same thing.

**My question is how to make the textbox at full screen while the input-group-btn at the same line and responsive**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc` to calculate right size.

```
.form-group.footable-filtering-search {
  width: calc(100% - 74px);
}
```

`74px` is total of your buttons' size. If you change it, you have update this.